Why is JEST tests generate another stack trace than Chrome/Firefox which causes test fail?
I have an LWC component and there is an @api variables with get/set wrapper around that. I have written a simplificator for it that passes data from api property and internal _property that uses new Error().stack to identify the name of the property. In Chrome/Firefox it works just fine thanks to the name after get/setters.
Code:
class A {
    api(...args) { console.log(new Error().stack); }
    _param;
    get param() { return this.api(); }
    set param(value) { this.api(value); }
}

Chrome:
Error
    at B.api (<anonymous>:7:21)
    at get param (<anonymous>:33:30)
    at <anonymous>:36:15

Firefox:
api@debugger eval code:7:21
get param@debugger eval code:33:30
@debugger eval code:36:13

From where I extract the param. But when running Jest tests, the stack is:
Error: 
    at eval (eval-f2e2fd06.repl:1:1)
    at Section.api (<filepath>)
    at Section.api (<filepath>)
    at Section.set (<filepath>)
    at setHook (<filepath>)

And no property name there.
Is it possible to bring the same behavior as Chrome? (since node runs on V8 too)
I tried to find the references about the stacktraces in Jest but thete wasn't any info how to modify this behavior. Seems there was no issues about it or noone else was using stacktraces in the work code (not in tests)

Does your last sentence mean that you have @api code that purposefully fires an exception, and you set out to test this? Can you outline a meaningful scenario in testing LWCs, where the stack trace is subjected to asserts? The presented Node stack trace is inconvenient for us as developers, but is there a reason why this is relevant for Jest tests?

@FelixvanHove, the idea is not to throw the error, but to capture the stack trace from it in order to identify what the name of the @ api property was called via getter/setter. There is the example in the first code block that describes the simplification wanted - I want to get rid of boilerplate in the get/set. So I search for the option to simplify the Jest stacktrace so the code will not fail in tests

Could you please add information regarding software versions you use to your question? Could you please also add the code that executes the test? I've just tried your example code, and got a meaningful stack trace that (I believe) would please you (2nd line starts "A.api [as param]..." etc.), using Jest 29.7.0. I tried Node.js 18.18.2, 20.16.0 and 22.7.0 and they produced similar output, but versions are important in this context.
